# accessing global variable from programmatic uibutton property

Tags: ios, swift

I want to use the same UIView class to record and play sound. In this view class, I add a button programmatically and I want to change the button text according to the purpose of the view. When the view is created as a player it will show play icon (or the text for now). If the view is created as a recorder it will show the record icon. But I cannot access global variable in the view from my UIButton.

```
class AudioPlayerView: UIView {
  var isRecorder = false

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

   ...

}
let theButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()

    if isRecorder {
        button.setTitle("▷", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(playPauseAudio), for: .touchUpInside)
    } else {
        button.setTitle("▢", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(recordTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    button.backgroundColor = .clear
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0
    return button
}()
```

Comment: you mean to say you are unable to access isRecorder variable?

Comment: Yes Syed. Exactly. But when I transfer the “isRecorder” above class deceleration, it works...

Comment: Why are you creating two views one for recording and one for playing as you can do it using a single view by just changing the isRecorder value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I made following in my viewcontroller class after I created the view. I simply set the button subview title and added relevant target. Now it seems to be functioning. But as a rookie, I am not sure if this is a good solution... Thanks every one who shared their comments and codes as well.

```
        if cell.name == "recorder" {
            audioPlayerView?.theButton.setTitle("▢", for: .normal)
            audioPlayerView?.theButton.addTarget(audioPlayerView, action: #selector(audioPlayerView?.recordTapped), for: .touchUpInside)

        } else {
            audioPlayerView?.theButton.setTitle("▷", for: .normal)
            audioPlayerView?.theButton.addTarget(audioPlayerView, action: #selector(audioPlayerView?.playPauseAudio), for: .touchUpInside)
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have re implemented your player class. Now you do not need to create two separate view for recording and playing status. All you need is to change the `isRecorder` value and your button title will be change without any need to create another view.

```
class AudioPlayerView: UIView {
    var isRecorder = false {
        didSet {
            if isRecorder {
                theButton.setTitle("▷", for: .normal)
            } else {
                theButton.setTitle("▢", for: .normal)
            }
        }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        if isRecorder {
            theButton.setTitle("▷", for: .normal)
        } else {
            theButton.setTitle("▢", for: .normal)
        }
        //Add your button to view as subview.
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    }
    let theButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.backgroundColor = .clear
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tapButton), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()

    func tapButton() {
        if isRecorder {
            playPauseAudio()
        } else {
            recordTapped()
        }
    }
    func playPauseAudio() {

    }
    func recordTapped() {

    }
}
```